public transit: Convert the route in Google Maps into non-bus
With a bus route, say <maps.google.com/?saddr= 5000 geary,sf &daddr= 1 geary,sf &dirflg= r>,
I need to convert the  type of the route into "not bus".
Ie, it can be a (patchwork of) walking route with the same path. Or a bicycle/car route.
How can it be done without going about it "manually"?

For sure, some routes cannot be converted due to having no sidewalks or having no car-pass etc, but how would I get a [best] close version of it?
